# Grails and release plugin

Tags: grails, release

I'm trying to use the release 2.0.4 plugin to deploy my war through grails 2.1.1 to artifactory server.

My BuildConfig.groovy has:

```
grails.project.repos.snap.url = "http://server:8080/artifactory/apps-snapshot-local"
grails.project.repos.snap.username = "user"
grails.project.repos.snap.password = "password"

grails.project.repos.rel.url = "http://server:8080/artifactory/apps-release-local"
grails.project.repos.rel.username = "user"
grails.project.repos.rel.password = "password"

grails.project.repos.default = "rel"
```

When I just do the "grails maven-deploy" it works and deploys to my rel server as expected.  When I try to override the default target through the command line I get failures.

```
grails maven-deploy --repository=snap
```

I get this:

```
| Done creating WAR snap
| POM generated: C:\dev-git\DBUpdateWeb\target/pom.xml.
| Error Error deploying artifact: C:\dev-git\DBUpdateWeb\target\DBUpdateWeb.war (The system cannot find the file specified)
| Error Have you specified a configured repository to deploy to (--repository argument) or specified distributionManagement in your POM?
```

When I do specify the --repository tag it doesn't generate a war even though it says it did.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grails maven-deploy "--repository=snap".

Also, specify app.version in application.properties so that the WAR will be standard compliant  (1.0-SNAPSHOT for publishing to the snapshots repository and 1.0 for releases), and comment out the grails.project.war.file line in BuildConfig.groovy.